# How should I arrange the separated boxes vertically?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How should I arrange the separated boxes vertically?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[4]{% width, height, depth, scale
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#4]
\foreach \x in {0,...,#1}
{   \draw (\x ,0  ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,#3 );
    \draw (\x ,#2 ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,0  );
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#2}
{   \draw (#1 ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,0  );
    \draw (0  ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,#3 );
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#3}
{   \draw (#1 ,0  ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
    \draw (0  ,#2 ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\tikzcube}[2]{% length, scale
\tikzcuboid{#1}{#1}{#1}{#2}
}

\tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \hspace{3cm} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4}

\vspace{3cm}


\tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \hspace{3cm} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{10}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4} \tikzcuboid{1}{1}{1}{0.4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to arrange the separated boxes like this:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you fill the side panesl with white or shades of gray, simply arrange them from bottom to top.  Wasteful, but effective.

Comment: Yes.  It works.  Thanks